# `vm.expectRevert` is not working as expected in Foundry

Tags: testing, foundry, unittesting, forge

Here is the file I am working with [SubscribeBySig.t.sol](https://github.com/ethereum-push-notification-service/push-smart-contracts/blob/230-migrate-comm-unit-tests/testFoundry/PushComm/unit_tests/SubscribeBySig/SubscribeBySig.t.sol) . You can replicate the scenario by cloning the above repo, switch to the `230-migrate-comm-unit-tests` branch and run `forge test`.

The problem is when I use `vm.expectRevert` knowing that the function call is goin to revert, I get the following error, means that the function didn't revert.
[image]

But the moment I comment out or remove the `vm.expectRevert` line from the test,  I again get an error, this time indicating that the function call reverted, which is obviously what I expected.

[image]

But why didn't the `expectRevert` catch this error in the first place? What am I doing wrong? I have also tried to use `expectRevert` with the error message, but nothing changed.

**UPDATE**: The tests pass when I use another method which is prefixing the function name with `testFail`. But I want to use `expectRevert`, still not sure what's the issue.

Comment: See this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/foundry-rs/foundry/issues/4762).

Comment: Thank you for taking this up ser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the issue.

Actually, I was passing a function call as an argument to another function call, which would be called obviously before the actual function call,  because of which the expectRevert method expected the argument to fail.[image]

Here is the solution if you wanna check out - [Commit](https://github.com/ethereum-push-notification-service/push-smart-contracts/pull/248/commits/0acf80d8e530f772b28a091f3f04c3ea6c5e6f7e)